# PowerPivot login system to SSAS

Tags: ssas, powerpivot

Is it possible to make a system in PowerPivot where i can choose specific user I want to use to login into SSAS server? By system i mean sth like pop-up window with user/password data or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

SSAS only works with windows authentication so no, you cant do that.

Answer (score 0):

It only supports Windows Authentication. Quote from MSDN

"SQL Server Analysis Services supports only Windows Authentication"

Refer to the following kb on how to set it up with Kerberos authentication: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917409

See if this offers any insight:
http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/tag/kerberos